# Intercept the request send from an ios app to a service, from Python and Appium

Tags: python, ios, json, networking, appium

I am working on a mac and I am trying to automate a certain app on an iPhone and at some point I am required to verify the request that the app sends to a service (more exactly a JSON request). I am using Appium to connect to the phone and Python to write the scripts.

I am aware that instruments has a network functionality that lets you inspect the network traffic of the app, but I am not sure if it also displays the JSON request.

So, I am looking for a wait to intercept the json request and make some assertions in the python script. Does anyone know some methods ?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of catching this and doing assertions in a python script? If you just want to test the correct calls are made you should do this in a unit test using a stub to catch your network call.

Comment: there are many reason a person wants to do it. When the app is build and we need to test the functionality of the App during integration phase making sure right network calls are made at the right time. I have tons of these cases automated functionally for my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar question few months back and some dumbs who are not even remotely concerned with Automation gave down votes to me as well. But anyways you have two solutions for this problem. I am not sure about instruments functionality so will not comment on it.

1) Use idevicesyslog to basically look at all the logs for your App in terminal , send them to a file and parse the file with what ever you are looking for. more info here http://krypted.com/tag/idevicesyslog/

But obviously app logs need to be turned on for this to work.

2) You will need to use a proxy to basically sniff the http requsts that your app is making. Now a days most of the traffic that is being sent commercially is all HTTPS so you might run into certificate issues with secured traffic. For the secured requests to work you need a stable proxy which sniff the traffic with certificates and all. I would suggest look at charles proxy. more information here [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com)

Comment: Ok, so assuming I use Charles proxy, is there a way to extract the data that charles collects from a python script ?

Comment: yes , it provides an API and web interface that you can control and export your session data into XML, HAR or CSV file and just parse the file. let me know if you have more questions. Also please accept the answer if it resolved your question.